# Android-Custom View to strictly remain within a layout custom bounds

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am designing a Canvas Drawable inside a layout. This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.sensennetworks.senanpr.ui.DrawPolygonCanvas
        android:id="@+id/drawPolygonCanvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="onSave"
        android:text="Save" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="onReset"
        android:text="Clear" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This  layout file creates a custom drawable "DrawPolygonCanvas" which can be dragged, in the image below this is dragged out of bounds.

[image]

And, this creates a result like this....where the result goes out of boundary completely.

[image]

Now my question is how do I create a layout such that the "DrawPolygonCanvas" is strictly inside a layout and it does not go outside it's boundary into the black area with both the buttons.

```
    // Debug helpers to draw lines between the two touch points
    private HashMap<String, List<Vector2D>> polygons = new HashMap();

    public DrawPolygonCanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public DrawPolygonCanvas(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public DrawPolygonCanvas(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    public DrawPolygonCanvas(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        Log.e(TAG, "called init");
        this.context = context;
//        Activity host = (Activity) getContext();
//        Log.e(TAG, "called getContext");
//        if (host.getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {
//            Log.e(TAG, "called hasExtra");
//            byte[] byteArray = host.getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray");
//
//
//            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray
//                    , 0, byteArray.length);
//            ((GlobalApp) context.getApplicationContext()).setCurrentPreviewBitmap(bm);
//        }
        Log.e(TAG, "calling setOnTouchListener");
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public void clearROI() {
        Log.e(TAG, "called clearROI");
        // Get ROI from the shared preferences.
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        cameraROI = sharedPreferences.getString(SettingsActivity.ROI, AnprSettings.DEFAULT_CAMERA_ROI);
        Log.e(TAG, "Reloaded ROI = " + cameraROI);
        convertString2Polygons();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.e(TAG, "called onDraw");
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (!isInitialized) {
            // Get ROI from the shared preferences.
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            cameraROI = sharedPreferences.getString(SettingsActivity.ROI, AnprSettings.DEFAULT_CAMERA_ROI);
            if (cameraROI.isEmpty()) {
                cameraROI = AnprSettings.DEFAULT_CAMERA_ROI;
            }
            convertString2Polygons();

            circlePaint = new Paint();
            circlePaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);

            linePaint = new Paint();
            linePaint.setColor(0xFF00FF00);
            linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            linePaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

            isInitialized = true;
        }


        Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

        // get
        Bitmap bm = ((GlobalApp) this.context.getApplicationContext()).getCurrentPreviewBitmap();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, null, dest, paint);

        try {
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<Vector2D>> entry : polygons.entrySet()) {

                List<Vector2D> polygon = entry.getValue();

                for (int i = 0; i < polygon.size() - 1; i++) {
                    canvas.drawLine(polygon.get(i).getX(), polygon.get(i).getY(), polygon.get(i + 1).getX(), polygon.get(i + 1).getY(), linePaint);
                }
                canvas.drawLine(polygon.get(polygon.size() - 1).getX(), polygon.get(polygon.size() - 1).getY(), polygon.get(0).getX(), polygon.get(0).getY(), linePaint);

                for (int i = 0; i < polygon.size(); i++) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(polygon.get(i).getX(), polygon.get(i).getY(), 40, circlePaint);
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        Log.e(TAG, "called onDetachedFromWindow");
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();

        // Convert polygon back to string.
        convertPolygons2String();

//        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = UserSharedPref.initializeSharedPreferencesForCameraROI(context).edit();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).edit();
        editor.putString(SettingsActivity.ROI, cameraROI);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.e(TAG, "called onTouch");
        canvasTouchManager.update(event);
        Vector2D vct = canvasTouchManager.getPoint();

        float minDist = 200000.0f;
        float radius = 200;

        int minIndex = -1;
        String key = "";

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Vector2D>> entry : polygons.entrySet()) {

            List<Vector2D> points = entry.getValue();
            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                float dist = points.get(i) == null ? 0 : Vector2D.subtract(vct, points.get(i)).getLength();
                if (dist >= radius) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (dist < minDist) {
                    minDist = dist;
                    minIndex = i;
                    Log.e(TAG, "Matching x = " + points.get(i).getX() + ", y = " + points.get(i).getY());
                    key = entry.getKey();
                }
            }
        }

        if (minIndex != -1 && !key.isEmpty()) {
            polygons.get(key).set(minIndex, vct);
        } else {
            Log.e("OK2", "Touch point is too far, dist = " + minDist);
        }

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: plz add the code that draw the DrawPolygonCanvas view

Comment: added the code @has19

Comment: Forget the java code.....is there a way to restrict a custom canvas drawable to a particular layout, such that it does not go out of the layout?

Comment: well you already have all the positions of the polygons ,so basically before drawing them on the screen just make sure all x,y positions of polygons are within the canvas width and height .if that's not the case than you need to scale the canvas based on a certain variable you need to calculate to decide how much to scale it

Comment: So are you sure, nothing can be done through the UI?